# How to use Atlas search on multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have two collections, that are store on Atlas.

I want to be able to search for a text, using the `regex` operator of Mongo Atlas Search on these two collections, but with only one aggregation.

These two collections have nothing in common, so I can't do a `$lookup` on it.

I need to do this search in one aggregation because the result of this aggregation **must be paginated** with $limit and $skip in the aggregation.

How to perform that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Atlas Data Lake on top of these two collections to federate queries across both.  To do this you would create a Data Lake, create a virtual collection in your Data Lake, and then have both of these collections listed as "datasources" for that virtual collection.

The Data Lake infrastructure will push down queries to the underlying cluster and union the results before returning them to the client application.

In this example there are multiple types of data sources, but you can just list multiple cluster collections.
https://docs.mongodb.com/datalake/reference/format/data-lake-configuration/#example-configuration-for-running-federated-queries